# Why CSV Reader (Java) adds space after comma while reading rows?

Tags: java, file, csv, parsing

I've a csv file where words are separated by commas in each rows, like:

word1,word2,word3,word4

word5,word6,word7,word8...and so on.

I'm able to parse it and read rows but when i print the lines it returns spaces after commas:

word1, word2, word3.....

```
BufferedReader r = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(new BlobstoreInputStream(blobKey)));

            @SuppressWarnings("resource")
            /*readinf from blob file*/
            CSVReader reader = new CSVReader(r,','); 
            String[] nextLine; 
            List<String> lines = new ArrayList<>();
            while ((nextLine = reader.readNext()) != null)
            {
                System.out.print(Arrays.toString(nextLine)+"\n");
            }
```

How can i remove space and get "word1,word2,word3...."?

UPDATE: I only need to remove space after commas and not space between words in commas. ("word1 another word2, word3, word4 and word5"--->"word1 another word2,word3,word4 and word5"

Answer (score 1):

The space is being added when you output the array using `Arrays.toString`.  It is NOT the CSV reader that is doing it.

If you want to format the array without spaces after the commas, you can use `StringJoiner`.  For example in Java 8 you can write:

```
 List<Integer> numbers = Arrays.asList(1, 2, 3, 4);
 String commaSeparatedNumbers = numbers.stream()
     .map(i -> i.toString())
     .collect(Collectors.joining(","));
```

If you need to use Java 7 or earlier:

- Point out to your manager that Java 7 was end-of-lifed a long time ago, and that continuing to use it is a security risk, and is bad for code quality going forward.
- You can implement what `StringJoiner` does using a loop and `StringBuilder` ... in about 5 lines of code.

  ```
  StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
  for (String s: array) {
      if (sb.length() > 0) sb.append(",");
      sb.append(s);
  }
  System.out.println(sb);
  ```

Comment: ok but i need to use Java 1.7. There is a way to retrieve rows without space after commas? Like, you know, removing space only after comma with regex or similar

Comment: I would advise against post-processing the formatted string.  You will get nasty surprises if the fields of the CSV contain spaces and/or commas.